# Retrieve all products from shopify using Alteryx Designer download tool

Tags: shopify, alteryx

I am trying to retrieve all products from shopify using Alteryx Designer Download Tool

Download tool takes an API URL as input and returns download data from it

https://exampleshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json

When i tried to input this URL its only giving me 50 products.

Is there anyway to fetch all products in Alteryx Designer?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the last line in the JSON returned. It should have a link for the next call of 50 items, however you may be able to put a payload into the original call with limit=250, meaning less iterative calls.

To deal with paginated API responses, an iterative macro can be used in Alteryx. You can find examples of such on the Alteryx Community.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I will definitely try that.